# Is the Advanced Security Pack required for windows authenticaion?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, security, windows, license

Can anyone tell me if the Oracle Advanced Security Pack is required for single sign in under Windows?

I've been told we are not licensed for the "Oracle Advanced Security Pack" and need to remove it, which appears to disable our existing externally identified logins.

Our version of Oracle is

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Try it on a development instance.

Comment: We have a development instance and windows authentication ('the EXTERNAL login with no password) suddenly stopped working. I asked why and I was told advanced security was removed. Nowhere can I find confirmation that advanced security is required to make this work. It just stopped working when they removed it

Comment: Yes, you will need Oracle Advanced Security. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e10746/asointro.htm#i1008433 But you no longer need a license for it as long as you're using it to authenticate database users with Windows AD (there may be other use cases which also qualify for free use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need Oracle Advanced Security to be *installed*. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e10746/asointro.htm#i1008433

However a *license* for Oracle Advanced Security is no longer needed with 11g Release 2, but you will apparently need a license for "Oracle Identity Management Directory Services Plus".

See PDF page 10 of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877.pdf

> Enterprise User Security is an EE feature for directory-based
>   management of database users. It does require a corresponding Oracle
>   Identity Management Directory Services Plus to be licensed. Usage of
>   Enterprise User Security with Oracle Database strong authentication
>   (PKI, Kerberos) no longer requires Oracle Advanced Security to be
>   licensed.

Comment: Thanks. My next challenge is to convince the DBA's of this.